# Providing Dependency Injection in an own reusable library

Tags: php, dependency-injection, composer-php

### Background

I am writing some reusable library, which contains few classes.
One of them needs to have a dependency, because of some more complex logic and I want to delegate the responsibility of that class somewhere else (another class).

### Goal

I don't want to create a bundle e.g. Symfony Bundle which could handle my dependency injection and provide a simple way to integrate it with a client code.
My goal is to provide reusable and framework independent solution.

### Additional information

I am using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and I've read about DI containers like [php-di](http://php-di.org/).
There is a [demo](https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo) application example by php-di, but it doesn't fit into my requirements.

### Example

Fragment of library code

```
<?php

class W3CAnalyzer implements WebStandardAnalyzer
{
   private $httpClient;

   public function __construct(HttpClient $httpClient)
   {
      $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
   }

   public function analyze(string $url): WC3AnalysisMetaData
   {
      $siteContent = $this->httpClient->getContent($url);

      //further logic there
   }
}
```

As you can see `W3CAnalyzer` contains the dependency `HttpClient` class.
I will somehow configure a DI container to register and resolve that dependency.

Sample client code

```
<?php

class WebStandardController
{
    private $webStandardAnalyzer;

    public function __construct(WebStandardAnalyzer $webStandardAnalyzer)
    {
       $this->webStandardAnalyzer = $webStandardAnalyzer;
    }
}
```

In client project, programmer will register `W3CAnalyzer` to be injected into controller as `WebStandardAnalyzer` using his DI configurations (it doesn't really matter how).

### The question

If I use some DI configuration and container in my library internally, how can I integrate this configuration with the client code, so there will be a possibility to register library class and all of its dependencies would have been resolved then?
I don't know yet, how I will organize DI inside my library (this is actually the first part of the problem), I want to somehow use the php-di library mentioned above.

To summarize, how to organize DI inside non-framework reusable library, so that library could be used inside every other project (no matter which framework is used) and its (that library) dependencies would also be resolved during runtime of that project.

Thank you!

Comment: @RyanVincent I've provided some additional explanation.

Comment: Dependency Injection is a principle. Your class `WebStandardController` uses it. A Dependency Injection Container **is not** required to use DI. It is just a convenient way to create objects and their dependencies using a single call.

Comment: @axiac and dependencies will be resolved automagically? Have you read my post?

Comment: Does a DIC automagically resolves the dependencies? I don't think so; it requires configuration. Does your library exports so many classes that it needs a DIC container to build them? Isn't a [Factory Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or several [Factory Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) enough? If you want to let the users of your library inject their own `HttpClient` implementations then a DIC embedded in the library stays in the way.

Comment: it requires configuration - that's the point and the problem. How to make this configuration compatible with different frameworks or with plain PHP project with composer only, that's my problem. I don't understand how factories would help me in my case (I know ofc what factory and factory method patterns are). Can you provide some example? Would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
class W3CAnalyzerFactory
{
    public function build()
    {
         $Subject = new W3CAnalyzer(new HttpClient);

         return $Subject
    }
}
```

The above is how I make use of the Factory pattern, and had great success with it. If `new HttpClient` is not sufficient for your code (that is, it needs to be built, too), then do the following:

```
class HttpClientFactory
{
    public function build()
    {
         //modify this to actually construct the HttpClient object, with
         //constructor and/or setter injections
         $Subject = new HttpClient();

         return $Subject
    }
}
```

Then, your `W3CAnalyzerFactory` will look like:

```
class W3CAnalyzerFactory
{
    public function build()
    {
         $Subject = new W3CAnalyzer(
             (new HttpClientFactory)
             ->build()
         );

         return $Subject
    }
}
```

Then, someone using your library can do something like the following:

```
$WebStandardController = new WebStandardController(
    (new W3CAnalyzerFactory())
    ->build()
);
```

Or, however they want using their own DI setup. As you said, it doesn't matter how they inject it, just that they can using the `W3CAnalyzerFactory` class, and that everything is then ready to go.

Tip: For all objects in my library and/or application I always made a factory class, even if there was nothing injected. It feels wordy at first, but has a couple benefits.

1. If you ever refactor a class (like `HttpClient`) so that it DOES now need to have something injected, then everything that uses `HttpClientFactory` is already done, and you don't need go through and replace all your `new HttpClient()` lines with `(new HttpClientFactory)->build()`.
2. You don't have to remember which of the injected implementations require a factory and which don't when building these factories. Everything does, so just use the factory. (i.e. Do I use `new HttpClient` or `(new HttpClientFactory)->build()`? Don't think about it, just use the factory.)

Creating these factories when you create the implementations is what I recommend, as it gets it out of the way and doesn't require you to come back later and try to think of how to string things together.

I think this approach is the simplest for dependency injection when you don't want to, or can't use a container to assist you.

Sidenote: The reason I assign the object to `$Subject` and then `return $Subject` a separate line instead of just doing `return new Whatever...` is because I tend to prefer setter injection, which means I need to do things to the object after it is constructed. You do what works best for your library and/or application though. The choice of the word "subject" as the variable name comes from calling my objects in my unit tests `$SUT` for "Subject Under Test". These aren't under test, so I just called them `$Subject` to have a nice consistent name that helps me easily see what object is the one being constructed. Again, that habit of mine is totally optional.

Comment: You implemented a mixtures of Builder and factory pattern.